# Matching an exact expression containing angular brackets

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to use sed to delete every occurrence of a particular pattern. The pattern is:

```
<Name>
```

I am using

```
sed g '/<Name>/d' file.txt
```

but this is giving me an error that says

```
sed: can't read /<Name>/d: No such file or directory
```

Clearly, the

```
<
```

is being taken as input stream. What is the way around this?

Comment: Try `sed 's/<Name>//g' file.txt`

Comment: Thanks! I also need to remove </Name>. I am trying sed 's/</Name>//g' file.txt but I am getting sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: The `/` must be escaped since it is used as a regex delimiter.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g` is a `sed` expression to append hold buffer to pattern buffer, as you have used it before the actual pattern it is being treated as the `sed` expression, and the rest `'/<Name>/d' file.txt` is being taken as arguments (files) hence the error regarding file `/<Name>/d` not being present.

As you want to remove all occurrences of `<Name>`, do:

```
sed 's/<Name>//g' file.txt
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove all lines that have `<Name>` in them:

```
sed '/<name>/d'  file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need to remove

Comment: Thanks! I also need to remove </Name>. I am trying sed 's/</Name>//g' file.txt but I am getting sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'.